# Почему анимация не работает нормально?

Tags: java, android

Спасибо @xkor который подсказал как можно сделать анимацию для `FrameLayout`

> Можно, например вот так:
>
> frame1.animate().alpha(1f).start(); // то что показываем, изначально должно быть с альфой 0
>       frame2.animate().alpha(0f).start(); // то что скрываем
>
> Это через прозрачность, если хотите перемещение то так:
>
> frame1.animate().x(0f).start(); // то что показываем, изначально должно быть скрыто за экраном
>       frame2.animate().x(-frame2.getX()).start(); // то что скрываем

У меня есть 2 `FrameLayout`

вот в такой разметке

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="60"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/registrationFrame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center|top"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.fontView.ExButton
                            style="@style/ExButton"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/stylelogbutton"
                            android:onClick="RegMe"
                            android:text="@string/registration_by_mail"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_white" />

                        <com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.fontView.ExTextView
                            style="@style/ExTextViewStyle"
                            android:layout_width="200dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            android:text="@string/agree"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                            android:textSize="15dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.fontView.ExTextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvAutAct3"
                        style="@style/ExTextViewStyle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:onClick="goToLogIn"
                        android:text="@string/i_am_already_user"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_white" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/loginFrame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.fontView.ExTextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvLogAct3"
                        style="@style/ExTextViewStyle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/log_in_by_e_mail"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_white" />

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tilEmailLog"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp">

                        <com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.fontView.ExEditText
                            android:id="@+id/etEmailLog"
                            style="@style/ExTextViewStyle"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            android:hint="@string/email"
                            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_white" />

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tilPasswordLog"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp">

                        <com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.fontView.ExEditText
                            android:id="@+id/etPasswordLog"
                            style="@style/ExTextViewStyle"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            android:hint="@string/password"
                            android:inputType="textPassword"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_white" />

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.fontView.ExButton
                        android:id="@+id/bLogIn"
                        style="@style/ExButton"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/stylelogbutton"
                        android:onClick="userLogIn"
                        android:text="@string/log_in"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.fontView.ExTextView
                        style="@style/ExTextViewStyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:onClick="forgotPassword"
                        android:text="@string/forgot_your_password"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_white" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

у меня есть кнопка при нажатии на которую фраймы меняются. Вот так

```
registrationFrame.animate().alpha(0).start();
        loginFrame.animate().alpha(1).start();
```

Но проблема в том, что когда я устанавливаю `registrationFrame` `alpha(0)`  то он красиво исчезает, но за ним ничего не появляется... Код вообще не реагирует на то, что `loginFrame` установлен `alpha(1)`...

Я сделал по другому, на одну кнопку поставил только функцию

```
registrationFrame.animate().alpha(0).start();
```

А на другую кнопку поставил функцию

```
loginFrame.animate().alpha(1).start();
```

Жму на первую все исчезает, жму на вторую ничего не появляется.((

Потом я попробовал одну и ту же функцию поставить на один и тоже фрайм `loginFrame` на эти 2 кнопки, только на в первом случае функция устанавливает `alpha(0)` а во втором `alpha(1)`...

Все работает для этого фрайма, он красиво исчезает, потом появляется.

Но почему это работает, только для одного и того же фрайма? Почему не получается сделать, чтоб один исчезал, а другой появлялся?

Comment: Попробуйте слушатель окончания анимации на анимацию повесить и при окончании исчезновения вьюхи делать ей видимсоть `View.GONE`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо очень выручили советом. Я немного докрутил эту идею и все получилось. Сейчас опубликую

Answer (score 1):

В итоге вот так у меня все заработало

```
public static void switch(final Context context) {
    firstFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    firstFrame.setAlpha(1);

    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.alpha_frame_off);
    registrationFrameOff.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            firstFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            secondFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Animation animNext = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.open_next);
            secondFrame.startAnimation(animNext);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    firstFrame.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Получается первый фрайм когда заканчивает выполнение анимации вызывается анимация для второго фрайма.